# Testing a directive that depends on another directive - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that contains another directive.  Here is the directive:

```
<div class="chat-container">
 <h5 class="chat-header">
  <span class="patient-name-container">{{encounter.patient.firstName }} {{encounter.patient.lastName}}</span></h5>
  <div ng-show="showMessages">
    <div  messages-container messages="encounter.comments"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my test:

```
  var element;
  beforeEach(module('app/views/chat.container.html'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
    var chatTemplate = $templateCache.get('app/views/chat.container.html');
    $templateCache.put('views/chat.container.html', chatTemplate);

    var directive = angular.element('<div chat-container max-chat-count="800" class="pull-left"></div>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));

  it('the remaining count to be 800', function() {
    expect(element.find('#counter').text()).toBe('800');
  });
});
```

My error is `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/messages.container.html`.  It is looking for the `html` to create the `messages-container` directive, but it cannot find it.  I have tried adding the other directive like this right after the first one:

```
var messagesTemplate = $templateCache.get('app/views/messages.container.html');
$templateCache.put('views/messages.container.html', messagesTemplate);
```

but I still get the same error, so I have 2 questions.
First - How do I test this?
Second - I am now creating my test with a dependency on another directive, what is the right way to handle that?

Comment: "but that still doesnt work" - was this the same error? It should work fine so long as the `$templateCache` is given the *messages.container* template before you `$compile` the `chat-container` one...and so long as you've loaded the module containing the second template.

Comment: I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me not adding the template with the `module` function before I tried to access it.  Here is the code that fixed the issue:

```
  var element, scope;
  beforeEach(module('app/views/chat.container.html'));
* beforeEach(module('app/views/messages.container.html'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
    var chatTemplate = $templateCache.get('app/views/chat.container.html');
    $templateCache.put('views/chat.container.html', chatTemplate);
    var messagesTemplate = $templateCache.get('app/views/messages.container.html');
    $templateCache.put('views/messages.container.html', messagesTemplate);
    var directive = angular.element('<div chat-container max-chat-count="800" class="pull-left"></div>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    scope = $rootScope;
  }));
```

I did not have the line with the `*` before.  Now everything works perfectly.